# How do I remove names from my Arraylist that dont match the names from my inbox?

Tags: android, string, arraylist, sms, contacts

This is my code for getting the contact names from my device. The problem I'm having is that in my listview, "elements" will display every name in contact list. Any ideas of how I can remove the names that have no SMS?

```
    // converts contacts from cursor to arraylist
    nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = getContacts();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        nameList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                     ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME )));
    }

    // convert arraylist to string array
    name = new String[nameList.size()];
    name = nameList.toArray(name);

    // new arraylist for after contacts with no messages are removed
    elements = new ArrayList<String>();

    //convert back to an arraylist
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
        elements.add(name[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that you need to retrieve the sms list and then do comparison to each contact number to find the actual number of SMS messages per contact. Once you have that you can remove the contacts from the list who have 0 messages. 
[This is a good link regarding working with SMS](http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging)